# How do you access all the extra areas on the map?

Tags: lotr-war-in-the-north

If you go onto the map and press X to zoom, you can see that there are dozens of other locations on the map that do not come into the main campaign. I have unlocked a couple, although I am not sure how, and they are levels that give you waves of enemies to try and survive. Are all the other locations like this and how do we access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access them, it's just "Lore".